# Use S3 TransferUtility with Content Uri

Tags: android, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

im trying to upload a file to S3 using the `TransferUtility`. I get the Uri via the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Intent.
The Result of the Intent looks something like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0000-0000:DCIM/Camera/20170811_105420_HDR.jpg`

I managed to Upload the File via a `AmazonS3Client` using `PutObjectRequest` and `InputStream` but I'd like to use `TransferUtility` and the `TransferObserver` for convenience and the ability to pause the upload.

My Code:

```
TransferUtility tU = TransferUtility.builder()
    .context(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
    .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider()))
    .build();

File f = new File(_uri.getPath());
TransferObserver tO = tU.upload("test.jpg", f);
```

crashes with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: /document/0000-0000:DCIM/Camera/20170811_105420_HDR.jpg
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:532)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:497)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:466)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:420)
                  at my.domain.myapp.aws.AwsConnector.uploadFile(AwsConnector.java:76)
                  at my.domain.myapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:26)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is a feature request to support contentUri / inputStream: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/1436

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File f = new File(_uri.getPath());
```

A `Uri` is not a file, and `TransferUtility` seems to demand a file. So, either:

- Stop using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and instead integrate [a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), so you can limit yourself to actual files, or
- Use the `Uri` and `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`, then use that stream to make a copy of the data to some file that you control, then upload that file.